# meteor.js: redux vs session variables & react state

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, redux

I was wondering if there is any reason to use redux with meteor, besides timetravel. I would just use react state for local UI state and session variables for state that is used in multiple components. I can see the benefit of redux with non meteor applications, but the availability of session variables and minimongo as a store seem to neglect the benefits of redux. Is there any advantage that I gain when using redux in meteor?

regards, Chris

Comment: I'm actually thinking about the same. Redux certainly has the benefit of living outside Meteor, so better community, support, reusability, and so on. But I'd like to keep it really simple. I'm curious about your current implementation of state management with reactive-vars|dict or minimongo! Could you show some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor 1.5 with GraphQl will use redux... I think, this is main idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apollo](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/redux.html) document, it creates its own internal Redux store and Meteor will [integrate Apollo stack in 1.5](https://forums.meteor.com/t/great-news-meteor-apollo-integration-coming-in-1-5/26494)

So Meteor 1.5 will default using redux !

Comment: This seems like a nice Setup but i think it will Take another 3-6 months to habe it Produktion ready ( full graphql/redux Integration with something similar to oplog tailing. So i am more Interested in the current state. Does redux Help when compared to Session variables, react state and Minimongo?